# c++ strftime something I dont know

Tags: c++, datetime

In linux env, I have some code as below:

```
std::string SecondsToDate10String(time_t seconds) {
    struct tm* t = localtime(&seconds);
    char buffer[100] = {'\0'};
    auto n = std::strftime(buffer, 10, "%Y%m%d%H", t);
    std::cout << "buffer => {" << buffer << "}" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "n => " << n << std::endl;
    return std::string(std::begin(buffer), std::begin(buffer) + 10);
}
```

when seconds = 1531903802
output is :
`buffer => {20180718}
n => 0`

I think the buffer should be 2018071816.
why?

Comment: when i run the code under mac, it is OK.

Comment: I pasted that epoch into https://www.epochconverter.com/ and it came back as "**GMT:** Wednesday, 18 July 2018 08:50:02", so the 18th is correct?!

Comment: `I think the buffer should be 20180716. why?` Yes, that is the question, why do you think it should be that?

Comment: Your maximum number of bytes to write is to small. You need `std::strftime(buffer, 11, "%Y%m%d%H", t)` to avoid `n==0`. `buffer => {2018071808}`, `n => 10` is correct.

Comment: sorry, i think the buffer should be 2018071816, maybe different zone the value is different.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, yes, you are correct, I missed the '\n'. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are triying to write more characters than the limit (10 in your code)

`std:strftime` output for `1531903802` is `2018071817`.
That's why your `n` is 0.

From [std::strftime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime):

> Return value
>
> The number of bytes written into the character array pointed to by str
>   not including the terminating '\0' on success. **If count was reached
>   before the entire string could be stored, ​0​ is returned and the
>   contents are undefined**.